# reapeted numbers in a list on python

Tags: python, list

Write a program that receives as input n elements of a list, and as output, prints True if there is an element that appears more than once, and False otherwise. This is what I already did, but it don´t works and I don´t know why, it keeps showing "False" to all.

```
lst = []
n = input().split()
flag = False
for i in n:
    if n.count(i) > 1:
        flag = True
        break
    print(flag)
```

Comment: "program that receives as input n elements of a list". Could you give an example of what sort of input you are thinking of? E.g. `[1,2,3]` or `1 2 3` or whatever. Remember that such inputs would be *strings*. Also, if you're going with `input()`, you'll probably want to check whether the input is of the correct expected type before trying to do the calculation.

Comment: the program should receive the amount of numbers that the list has and then receive the list and then show true if there are repeated numbers and false if not, mine shows false everytime

Answer (score 1):

You should do `print` *after* loop, not *inside*, that is

```
lst = []
n = input().split()
flag = False
for i in n:
    if n.count(i) > 1:
        flag = True
        break
print(flag)
```

Comment: the program should receive the amount of numbers that the list has and then receive the list and then show true if there are repeated numbers and false if not, mine and yours show false everytime

Comment: @Lucas I did provided `5 5 5` as input and got `True` as required

Comment: This is the most simple and clean answer. @Lucas for array length you can use `print(len(n))`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.Just checking if there is a space in it's string type.

**EDIT:** no need to create a loop for that indeed.you can use it like this.

```
lst = []
n = input().split()
flag = False

if " " in str(n):
    flag = True

print(flag)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `hash` / `dictionary` to get the frequency of each number, and once a number is found in dictionary then return `False`  as we have encountered the duplicate element.

```
frequency = {}
n = list(map(int, input().split()))
flag = False
for i in n:
    if i not in frequency:
        frequency[i] =1
    else:
        flag = True
        break
print(flag)
```